# Como implementar uma fila de processos em Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, multithreading, log, delphi-6, fila-thread

Como implementar uma fila de processos em ***Delphi 6*** como a `TThread.Queue` das versões mais novas?

O que eu preciso é implementar uma fila para gravação de logs com Delphi 6. Nas versões mais novas eu tenho a possibilidade de utilizar:

```delphi
procedure TFormClient.QueueLogMsg(const s: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      LogMsg(s)
    end
  );
end;
```

Estive pensando em criar uma thread que faria isso, mas não sei se terei erros ao tentar adicionar um novo processo na lista de processos enquanto a thread estiver executando.

O que pensei:

```delphi
TQueueLog = class(TThread)
private
  FLog: TStringList;
  FFile: TStringList;
  FFileName: string;
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure AddLog(value: string);
  procedure Execute; override;
end;
...

constructor TQueueLog.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate := false;
  FLog := TStringList.Create;
  FFile := TStringList.Create;
  FFileName := 'log.txt';
end;

destructor TQueueLog.Destroy;
begin
  FLog.Free;
  FFile.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

E os métodos `AddLog` e `Execute`:

```delphi
procedure TQueueLog.AddLog(value: string);
begin
  FLog.Add(value);
end;

procedure TQueueLog.Execute;
var
  count: integer;
begin
  while (not Self.Terminated) do
  begin
    if (FLog.Count > 0) then
    begin
      FFile.LoadFromFile(FFileName);
      for count := 0 to pred(FLog.Count) do
      begin
        FFile.Add(FLog.Strings[count]);
      end;
      FFile.SaveToFile(FFileName);
      FLog.Clear;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Então, **como impedir a violação de acesso ao tentar adicionar um item ao `FLog` pelo 
`AddLog` quando a thread estiver em execução? Existe uma outra forma, correta, de implementar isso?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para impedir erros neste tipo de operação você deve controlar a concorrência utilizando, por exemplo uma critical section.

Para isso você vai precisar de um objeto do tipo `TCriticalSection`

```delphi
TQueueLog = class(TThread)
private
  FLog: TStringList;
  FFile: TStringList;
  FFileName: string;
  FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;

  function GetLogs: string;
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure AddLog(value: string);
  procedure Execute; override;
end;
...

constructor TQueueLog.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate := false;
  FLog := TStringList.Create;
  FFile := TStringList.Create;
  FFileName := 'log.txt';
  FCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

destructor TQueueLog.Destroy;
begin
  FLog.Free;
  FFile.Free;
  FCriticalSection.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Proteger o método que adiciona logs

```delphi
procedure TQueueLog.AddLog(value: string);
begin
  FCriticalSection.Acquire;
  try
    FLog.Add(value);
  finally
    FCriticalSection.Release;
  end;
end;
```

E criar um método que lê, de forma protegida, os logs adicionados

```delphi
function TQueueLog.GetLogs: string;
begin
  FCriticalSection.Acquire;
  try
    result := FLog.CommaText;
    FLog.Clear;
  finally
    FCriticalSection.Release;
  end;
end;
```

E ao executar você lê, de forma protegida, os logs e opera com eles em memória

```delphi
procedure TQueueLog.Execute;
var
  count: integer;
  CurrentLogs: TStringList;
begin
  CurrentLogs := TStringList.Create;
  try
    while (not Self.Terminated) do
    begin
      CurrentLogs.CommaText := GetLogs;
      if (CurrentLogs.Count > 0) then
      begin
        FFile.LoadFromFile(FFileName);
        for count := 0 to pred(CurrentLogs.Count) do
        begin
          FFile.Add(CurrentLogs.Strings[count]);
        end;
        FFile.SaveToFile(FFileName);
        CurrentLogs.Clear;
        Sleep(200);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CurrentLogs.Free;
  end;
end;
```